# How to declare this function in jQuery? $(document).ready is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fcbkcomplete

I am using FCBKcomplete. I don't know the reason why my UI is not accepting any function triggered under `$(document).ready`.

I have to trigger the function below for Facebook like auto-complete, just like http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
        json_url: "data.txt",
        addontab: true,
        maxitems: 10,
        input_min_size: 0,
        height: 10,
        cache: true,
        newel: true,
        select_all_text: "select"
    });
});
```

But it's not working. Other events, such as `click`, `blur` and all are working fine in my UI. Is there any alternative function which I can use instead of `document.ready`?

Comment: Your example works fine... and `document ready` *is* the correct event.

Comment: Sure that `$(document).ready` is your problem? Have you tried to alert something inside of the event?

Comment: @Armin I have tried but nothing worked....in firebug. the error is coming like this...  $("#select3").fcbkcomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error] select_all_text: "select",

Comment: @TheifMaster yes it works fine when tried outside my UI..but it clashes all the css when i use it with my UI. particularly document ready is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some other include of a javascript library is using the $ (dollar sign) already as a selector. So if you get the `$(document).ready is not a function` error or similar ones (like your `$("#select3").fcbkcomplete is not a function`), you'll have to build in a "**body guard**" functionality like:

```
( function($) {
    // we can now rely on $ within the safety of our “bodyguard” function
    $(document).ready( function() { 
        alert("Yay I can use '$'!!");  
    } );
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: @Bala.C: Be conscious of the error I pointed out in my answer. It was part of the error that you posted in the comments on the question. Are you using another Javascript library?

Comment: @Purmou Nope am not using any other js libraries other than jquery. It must be due to some other function conflicted with this.. and yes i noticed and fixed the error u said. Thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select_all_text: "select",
```

There shouldn't be a comma after the last option (`select_all_text`) in the `fcbkcomplete()` function.